# Python segmentation fault when using zipfile while GDAL package loaded

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, gdal

I'm encountering a weird segmentation fault error while trying to extract a ZIP file using the `zipfile` module while having imported the `osgeo.gdal` module (not exclusively, `osgeo.ogr` yields the same error -- maybe it's related to both modules using SWIG?).

I was able to narrow the crash down to the specific import of `osgeo.gdal`, see the example below. Running the Python interpreter with GDB seems to suggest that the crash stems from an invalid `free()` invocation somewhere in zlib, but unfortunately I lack the experience to dig any further there.

Does anybody have a guess as to what might be going wrong here? Or maybe some pointers (heh) as to how to best debug a problem like this?

Thanks a ton!

Edit: After some more sleuthing, I found a similar issue being reported against the Conda-provided GDAL package (https://github.com/conda-forge/gdal-feedstock/issues/365). The suggested workaround to move the GDAL module import to the end of the imports list fixed the segfault, so there's that! Still, I appreciate any answers that could point me in the right direction to debug a problem like this :)

#### Offending Code, (almost) minimal example

```py
# >>> Comment this import to make the segfault disappear
from osgeo import gdal
# <<<

import io
import tempfile
import zipfile
import urllib3
import faulthandler

class GadmDownloader:
    BASE_URL_TEMPLATE = 'https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/gpkg/gadm36_{}_gpkg.zip'

    def __init__(self):
        self.http = urllib3.PoolManager()

    def download_country(self, country, output_dir = None):
        url = self.BASE_URL_TEMPLATE.format(country.upper())

        resp: urllib3.HTTPResponse = self.http.request('GET', url)
        if resp.status != 200:
            raise RuntimeError(f'Download failed: {resp.status}')

        faulthandler.enable()
        with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(resp.data), 'r') as zipf:
            gpkg = [name for name in zipf.namelist()
                    if name.endswith('.gpkg')]
            zipf.extract(gpkg[0], output_dir)
        return gpkg[0]


def main():
    gdal.UseExceptions()

    dl = GadmDownloader()
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
        path = dl.download_country('gmb', tempdir)
        print(f'>> Path: {path}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output**

```
$ python -X dev gadm.py                                                                                                                                                                                               (minikube:default)
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py:15: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import imp
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007ffb15579740 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 724 in _get_decompressor
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 819 in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1571 in open
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1700 in _extract_member
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1630 in extract
  File "gadm.py", line 29 in download_country
  File "gadm.py", line 38 in main
  File "gadm.py", line 42 in <module>
[1]    200128 segmentation fault (core dumped)  python -X dev -d -X showmalloc gadm.py
```

**GDB Backtrace**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e3aa50 in free () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7e3aa50 in free () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff485ae0f in inflateReset2 () from /usr/lib/libcfitsio.so.9
#2  0x00007ffff39ec1a4 in inflateInit2_ () from /usr/lib/libz.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff74a7880 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
#4  0x00007ffff7b466ad in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#5  0x00007ffff7b43097 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#6  0x00007ffff7b4f138 in _PyFunction_Vectorcall () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#7  0x00007ffff7b3e77c in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#8  0x00007ffff7b3d0c4 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#9  0x00007ffff7b47095 in _PyObject_FastCallDict () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#10 0x00007ffff7b59c2f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#11 0x00007ffff7b47c90 in _PyObject_MakeTpCall () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#12 0x00007ffff7b42fc4 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#13 0x00007ffff7b3d7e2 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#14 0x00007ffff7b5e982 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#15 0x00007ffff7b3f553 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#16 0x00007ffff7b3d7e2 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#17 0x00007ffff7b4f1cd in _PyFunction_Vectorcall () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#18 0x00007ffff7b3eb41 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#19 0x00007ffff7b3d0c4 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#20 0x00007ffff7b4f1cd in _PyFunction_Vectorcall () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#21 0x00007ffff7b3eb41 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#22 0x00007ffff7b3d0c4 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#23 0x00007ffff7b4f1cd in _PyFunction_Vectorcall () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#24 0x00007ffff7b3eb41 in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#25 0x00007ffff7b4f138 in _PyFunction_Vectorcall () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#26 0x00007ffff7b3e77c in _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#27 0x00007ffff7b3d0c4 in _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#28 0x00007ffff7bee323 in PyEval_EvalCode () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#29 0x00007ffff7bf9b98 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#30 0x00007ffff7bf3db3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#31 0x00007ffff7ab2a0b in PyRun_FileExFlags () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#32 0x00007ffff7ab2482 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#33 0x00007ffff7c06a1a in Py_RunMain () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#34 0x00007ffff7be2bd9 in Py_BytesMain () from /usr/lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0
#35 0x00007ffff7dd6002 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#36 0x000055555555504e in _start ()
```

#### System facts

- Linux 5.7.10-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 22 15:23:40 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Arch/Manjaro Linux
- Python 3.8.5
- GDAL 3.0.4

Comment: If you want success, you won't rush. `self.http = urllib3.PoolManager()
`

Answer (score 2):

Doing the Python imports in reverse alphabetical order solves this issue.